# Keyboard does not resign from view

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a search bar in my app. The search bar is connected via a delegate to the main view controller. Even with textFieldShouldReturn and searchBarSearchButtonClicked nothing is happening.

I have tried to reconnect the delegate, and set the searchbar.delegate as self in my code (Results in a crash)

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( _ searchBar: UISearchBar!){
    print("Testing")
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {    
    textField.resignFirstResponder()        
    view.endEditing(true)

    return true
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if either of those two methods are actually being called? `textFieldShouldReturn` is for a `UITextField`, not a search bar. Make sure the search bar's delegate is set.

Comment: I have confirmed that the search bar delegate is set.

Comment: Can you share the crash logs?

Comment: It is a sigabrt error.

Comment: You state "nothing happens" followed by "results in a crash". Which is it? Nothing or a crash? If a crash, please point out the line causing the crash and post, as text, the complete error message.

Comment: I have also set the search bar as a delegate in the main storyboard file. It only crashes when the search bar delegate is assigned in the view controller.swift file.

Comment: Nothing happens when the delegate is set via the main storyboard.

Comment: This is what crashes the app: urlEnter.delegate=self as! UISearchBarDelegate

Comment: Don't add the `as! UISearchBarDelegate`. It's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `UISearchBarDelegate` in your class `ViewController`.